# An idea for a complex function that finds in a sorted list of integers a number not bigger than a given one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have, say, in A1 a text containing a sorted (eventually reversed) list of integers separated by some not-digit-char - for example "10, 123, 230, 750, 1034, 2003, 10101"; in B1 I have an integer *n*; I need a formula *not involving other cells* that returns:

- *n* if *n* belongs to the list in A1;
- otherwise, if *n* is not bigger than the maximum value in A1, the value in A1 immediately bigger than *n* (e.g., for *n* = 567 the returned value must be 750);
- otherwise, an error.

In my opinion, the only way to solve the problem concerns regexp substitution (that Google Sheet supports), but until now I can't find a reasonable way to proceed.

Someone has a (different) idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

`=index(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ")),1,0),
MATCH(B1,SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ")),1,0),-1))`

in this formula I used `search_type` = -1 for [`match function`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en):

> MATCH(search_key, range, search_type)
>
> 1. search_key - The value to search for. For example, 42, "Cats", or
>      I24.
> 2. range - The one-dimensional array to be searched. If a range with both height and width greater than 1 is used, MATCH will return #N/A!.
> 3. search_type - [ OPTIONAL - 1 by default ] - The manner in which to
>      search.
>
> ---
>
> - 1, the default, causes MATCH to assume that the range is sorted in    ascending order and return the largest value less than or equal to
>     search_key.
> - 0 indicates exact match, and is required in situations where range is    not sorted.
> - **-1 causes MATCH to assume that the range is sorted in descending order and return the smallest value greater than or equal to search_key.**

---

## Simplify the case

Suppose you have a cell with text sorted in descending:

[image]

The formula would be:

```
=index(SPLIT(A1,", "),MATCH(B1,SPLIT(A1,", "),-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=if(isnumber(find(B1,A1)),B1,index(split(A1,","),match(B1,split(A1,","),1)+1))
```

Above won't work for numbers lower than the first, but if required could be expanded to:

```
=if(B1<1*left(A1,find(",",A1)-1),1*left(A1,find(",",A1)-1),if(isnumber(find(B1,A1)),B1,index(split(A1,","),match(B1,split(A1,","),1)+1)))
```

Comment: Nice. I forgot about the split command. I've gotten rusty in my time away.

Comment: pnuts, your formula is great and introduces me to the MATCH function that, due to a very bad explanation in the italian Google Sheet's Functions reference, was obscure to me. Unfortunately your formula is not perfect, due to the "isnumber(find(..." that makes confusion with small numbers. See the example (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11iOn9IN8PstA2XhDaIswtoNDmTjonGE30dOI5Djyzdc/edit#gid=0) I published, where your formula is in column C.